# Why does SFDC mean Salesforce?

Tags: naming-convention

I am curious to know why SFDC has come to be associated with Salesforce.

Comment: I answered and then I saw your profile :/ you are messing around arent you ;) :P

Comment: why would I be messing around? just because I used to work for Salesforce and am a customer of Salesforce doesn't mean that I know the reason. Furthermore it's the first time I have heard that DC represents Dot Comc or .com in any acronym. Have you any other examples to enlighten me? It is you who are messing I fear! :-)

Comment: I was also very curious, what a waste of curiosity. SFDC, should really be SF only

Comment: Correct, thats what our perception is now. But maybe the stakeholders has different perception then, in initial days when 'San Francisco > Salesforce':)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**SFDC** stands for **Salesforce.com** (**S**ales **F**orce **D**ot **C**om)

The company chose SFDC over the simpler SF to avoid confusing with the common acronym for the company's hometown of San Francisco!

Comment: I can't find a reference at the moment, but I believe they are trying to move away from SFDC, though this is correct as far as the origin goes.

Answer (score 6):

SFDC stands for **S**ales**F**orce**D**ot**C**om. The company would have retained just SF. But as trends on Social Communities started getting wider the acronym faced the uncertainty of getting hijacked by other trends.

For ex: Initially on Twitter, Salesforce used both **#Salesforce** and **#SF** as hashtags to monitor the interactions. Later, it got too crowded to use **#SF** since it may be SemiFinal of an event etc. So then it decided to switch to **SFDC**. Now this has gained the prominent Keyword status on many communities(including Stackexchange) and also on Google Rankings.